# How can I write tests for web services (in C#) outside of the Solution they exist in?

Tags: c#, web-services, testing, load-testing, functional-testing

I have been recently added to a project where I will need to be doing functional and load testing for some existing Web Services (SOAP).

I was wondering if it is possible to call a web service from a console application for testing purposes?  I do not have permissions to code in the existing Project so I need to create a new one, which is what my real issue is, I do not know how to call the web services (or the web service code) from outside of their Solution.

I know this will make things more difficult, especially for recording test results, but I have no choice as I am a contractor and can not get the required permissions.  I can pull code and see the source code, I just don't want to code in the existing project as my local changes will get blown away every time there is new code to pull down.

I have done some basic testing using SoapUI, but the open Source version does not meet all the requirements I have and would rather just write my own tests then try and find a free 3rd party solution (as I also have no budget).

Thanks,
cwlovell13

Comment: It sounds like you're doing API testing rather than unit testing in which case you don't need any access to the code and should just be calling the web service in the same way a client would; with an http request.

Comment: Thank you for the swift response, I will look into this.  Any other help & tips would be appreciated!

Comment: As far as tips go, get fiddler or some other web proxy. Go through use cases on the client and observe the contract the API defines. Then just write code that makes those same requests but does data validation on the responses rather than just bubbling it up to the presentation layer. I've never worked with SOAP so I can't comment there. If you don't already know about the webrequest classes in .NET, familiarize yourself with them. Also, what is your data format? If you're not familiar with a serializer/deserializer for that then find one and get used to it. I recommend json.NET for json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a simple WCF client to consume existing Web Services (SOAP).
Maybe you can reference this .
[Accessing Services Using a WCF Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734691.aspx)